# HCS12 -- Program gets stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: assembly

I am new to assembly. I'm using the HCS12 and AsmIDE software. After I assemble and download the program, I run 'g $1500' (where  $1500 can be any other address). Then nothing gets updated in the terminal, and I can't enter anything. It seems to be stuck in an infinite loop.

Another occasion, my program ran perfectly once. I went to a different program, and that got stuck. So, I went back to the first perfectly working program, and now it won't run either.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Example of program:

```
      org $1500

      ldx #5

      end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not exiting your program properly. It executes the `ldx` instruction and then continues to execute whatever happens to be after your program in memory. End the routine with `rts` before the `end` and see if it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: When I added 'rts', nothing changed. 'Rts' is supposed to be for subroutines, but my code doesn't contain that. Right? Anyway, the problem changed. I examined the microcontroller's memory, and none of my program is getting downloaded into it. It loaded once, and now nadda. That's probably why it's not exiting properly. I don't know what to do next. I do the proper procedure: assemble -> reset -> load -> download and nothing gets downloaded into the memory.

Comment: From the viewpoint of the environment/OS, your program *is* a subroutine. If you don't have any special means of exiting a program explicitly, rts is the way to go.

Comment: If you code doesn't even end up in memory, of course it won't work. I'm afraid I can't help you with the transfer. Is this homework? Then you should have a teacher to ask.